# Libreoffice Calc SUM returns ###

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

In Libreoffice Calc, sometimes the SUM function returns ### in the cell when referencing other sums.  For example:

```
=SUM(x1+y1)
```

where

```
x1=sum(a1:d1)
y1=sum(a2:d2)
```

gives

```
###
```

in the output cell. (obviously this is not my real data)

Sometimes the function outputs correctly if I re-make it.  It also tends to error like this when I change the values of the referenced cells.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the column wider.  The number is too big to fit.

Comment: Boy, don't I feel stupid. :/  Thanks for the solve!

Comment: NP.  Glad I could help.